# How do I change my closet doors?

Tags: doors, glass, closet

I have an old wall closet wich has dark brown wooden doors with a little frame for decoration.
Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/d8CpQNpK).

I would like to achieve this kind of doors:
[image: gloss/mirror doors]

With gloss or dark mirror.
The think is that I can remove the frame I told you above, so that the wooden surface would be even.
So I thought that I could buy a dark mirror and somehow glue the mirror to the door.

What do you think?
Also, I would like a solution for the handles of the door.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You need somewhat thick glass for a clean flat undistorted appearance, which is quite heavy in large sizes. You very likely will need upgraded hinge hardware to handle the extra weight.

Comment: You also need a fairly sturdy doorframe to support a large expanse of glass